# Get button value to javascript array and save to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I have 3 buttons with 3 different value. When i click buttons then all values insert to javascript array.How do I do like that?

```
<input type="button" id="marksel" class="slmodel" onclick="getvalm();" value="John" />
<input type="button" id="marksel" class="slmodel" onclick="getvalm();" value="Alex" />
<input type="button" id="marksel" class="slmodel" onclick="getvalm();"  value="Martin" />
```

and javascript function is

```
function getvalm() {
                var a = [];
                $( ".slmodel" ).click(function (){
                    a.push($( this ).val());
                });
                alert(a);
            }
```

When i use alert to show array result then nothing to show. And how do I insert this 3 data to mysql database using javascript array?

Comment: you can add class active to most recent element.

Comment: please explain your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve solution to your problem like :

1. while $(this).addClass("smodel"); you can push value of the select span to an array so that you can have multiple selected values in one array which can be saved.
2. While fetching data values to save in database fire a javascript function collecting values of all the span having class 'smodel'.

Comment: `var markselected = [];
if($('#marksel').val()!=null){ markselected.push($('#marksel').val()); }
  console.log(markselected);`

Comment: it is getting no result

Comment: i changed     <span id="marksel" class="smodel" value="Nokia 108">Nokia 108</span>

Comment: span is not an input element so better you should use .attr to get value as:  `if($('#marksel').hasClass('smodel')){ markselected.push($('#marksel').attr('value');)}`